# Is a rare timeout from a ping on 5ghz normal?

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, timeout, wifi-configuration

I have a ASUS router with a 5ghz AP. No interference or traffic. My question is, what can cause even just one timeout out of a large number (say, 10,000) successful, low-roundtrip times (1-2ms)? Sounds a little obsessive, but I'm just curious why even one can time out. Is this just considered normal for wireless, even one with no traffic and no interference? Thanks.

Comment: so are you pinging between a wifi client and a computer on your LAN ? When you say no interference - are there any walls between the WiFi router and the WiFi client ?

Comment: Yes I am. By "no interference", I mean very little traffic (this is a home network) and yes, there are two walls between my laptop and the AP, though total distance is less than 20 feet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious how you determine that there is no interference, but that aside, it depends on what you are pinging.  If you are pinging a host on the Internet, the packet could have been lost between the AP and the destination host.  If you are pinging the AP directly, it is a little unusual for the conditions described, but it seems unlikely for wireless to be quite as reliable as a wired network.  .01% packet loss seems a little high for a wireless network with no interference, but I wouldn't be surprised at a 10th or hundredth that level.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I'm pinging a local machine on my LAN. I say "no interference" meaning no APs on the same channel. My AP is an ASUS RT-N66U, so it's not some cheap router.

Answer (score 0):

Packet loss on a local network generally shouldn't happen. 1 out of 10,000 could be anything. Dropped by router, poor router placement (emi/rfi), failed transmission on media to other device, or due to excessive network traffic.

With a 2ms response time I would rule out network traffic and just call it a random comm error.

Comment: I have a pretty decent ASUS router, though. The laptop is only about 20 feet away, though it's separated by two thin walls. What do you mean by a "random comm error"? Is that just considered normal? As I mentioned, every other ping is 1-2ms.